# Efficiently transform a list of vectors into a matrix

Tags: r

I have a list of free sized vectors

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- lapply(1:10, \(x) sample(letters, size = sample(1:10,1), replace = T))

dat

[[1]]
[1] "d" "g" "a" "b" "w" "k" "n" "r" "s"

[[2]]
[1] "u"

[[3]]
[1] "j" "v" "n" "j" "g"

[[4]]
[1] "o" "u" "e" "i" "y" "n" "e" "e" "b"

[[5]]
 [1] "y" "l" "o" "a" "t" "c" "f" "j" "j" "f"
```

What are some ways to make a dense matrix like this one, but more efficiently?
Also I would like to save the column names like in the example

```
library(arules)
as(transactions(dat), "matrix")


          a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l     m
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
          n     o     r     s     t     u     v     w     x     y     z
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[10,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This is an example from the аrules package and is not optimized for my purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly faster and more memory efficient than the nice solution of @ThomasIsCoding:

```r
mdummy <- function(dat) {
  n <- length(dat)
  vec <- as.factor(unlist(dat, FALSE, FALSE))
  lvls <- levels(vec)
  out <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = n, ncol = length(lvls), dimnames = list(NULL, lvls))
  out[cbind(rep(seq_len(n), lengths(dat)), as.integer(vec))] <- TRUE
  out
}
```

A quick benchmark with 100 vectors:

```r
set.seed(1)
dat <- lapply(1:100, \(x) sample(letters, size = sample(1:10,1), replace = T))

bench::mark(
  table(rep(seq_along(dat), lengths(dat)), unlist(dat)) > 0,
  mdummy(dat),
  check = FALSE
)

# expression        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   1 table()     232µs  267µs     3331.     111KB     8.46  1576     4      473ms <NULL>
#   2 mdummy(dat) 100µs  118µs     7104.    45.2KB     6.32  3373     3      475ms <NULL>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
t(table(stack(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat))))) > 0
```

which gives a table

```
> t(table(stack(setNames(dat, seq_along(dat))))) > 0
    values
ind      a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l
  1   TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  3  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  4  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  5   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  9  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  10  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
    values
ind      m     n     o     r     s     t     u     v     w     x     y     z
  1  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  3  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  4  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  5  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
  7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  9   TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  10 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

A shorter (and might be more efficient than my previous `stack` approach) version is

```
> table(rep(seq_along(dat), lengths(dat)), unlist(dat)) > 0

         a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l
  1   TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  3  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  4  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  5   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
  8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
  9  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  10  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

         m     n     o     r     s     t     u     v     w     x     y     z
  1  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  2  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  3  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  4  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  5  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  6  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
  7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
  8  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
  9   TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  10 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you! Great example! but table() is quite slow, I wonder what other options there are

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
f <- function(dat) {
  x <- unlist(dat)
  u <- sort(unique(x))
  m <- matrix(FALSE, length(dat), length(u), 0, list(NULL, u))
  m[cbind(rep.int(seq_along(dat), lengths(dat)), match(x, u))] <- TRUE
  m
}
```

Benchmark:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- lapply(1:100, \(x) sample(letters, size = sample(1:10,1), replace = T))

bench::mark(
  f = f(dat),
  mdummy = mdummy(dat)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f             113µs    122µs     7205.    67.4KB     6.53
#> 2 mdummy        136µs    154µs     5386.    45.2KB     4.18
```